# multiple buttons in one component TypeError: onChange (prop) is not a function (dealing with props) React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, react-props

I've a react native component which has multiple buttons in it, each button is a choice and user can have one or multiple choices (more about the idea in the image below). What I need here is `onClick` on of any of the buttons inside the component I wanna take those choices and store them somewhere else.

The problem is when I press on a button it doesn't gets saved immediately it just logs the previous value how can I return the onChange prop with the updated value.

snack working demo: https://snack.expo.io/OXhu3r-SX

here is my component:

Note: removed styling for better readability

```
const InputButton = ({ defaultValue = null, isMultiple, onChange, options, styled, alwaysGreen }) => {
  const initValue = isMultiple ? defaultValue || [] : defaultValue;
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initValue);

  const updateValue = (option) => {
    if (isMultiple) {
      // onClick if option is not inclded in the array **add it** otherwise **remove it**
      !value.includes(option) ? setValue([...value, option]) : setValue(value.filter((v) => v !== option))
    } else {
      setValue(option);
    }
    onChange(value)
  };

console.log("if I log the value here it's good to go and updated, updated value is >", value)

  return (
    <View>
      {options &&
        options.map((option, i) => (
          <TouchableOpacity key={`${i}`} onPress={() => updateValue(option)}>
            <Text>
              {option}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
    </View>
  );
};

export default InputButton;
```

[image: Here is the Idea]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main Error here is that I'm just passing a `useEffect` containing the `onChange(value)` as the answer of our friend here @jnpdx but I was just getting that crazy error `TypeError: onChange is not a function` and my problem wasn't fixed at all... but **Eventually** I've **solved** this problem by giving the `onChange` prop (first line) a default value like so:

`const InputButton = ({ defaultValue = null, isMultiple = true, onChange = ()=> null }) => {`

Here I'm explicitly saying that onChange is **by default** a function, think of it like that guys whenever we get a **TypeError** we have to give everything in that component (not only props) a default type.

Comment: That is only true in the case that there was somewhere you weren’t explicitly passing onChange to it.

Comment: This just provides a default value in the event that you don’t or forget to pass onChange. Search your codebase and you’ll find somewhere you cal it without passing onChange. Original answer is still correct.

Comment: Here's a snack where you can tell the difference: https://snack.expo.io/ax_S4y6jA Note that if the line with onChange defined is commented out, you get an error. If you pass onChange to the component, though, you don't get the error.

Comment: That's what was blowing up my mind actually... because it's working on **snack**!!! try initializing an app using react-native init MyProject locally and it will never work even if you pass a function to it in the parent component **Note** : my app is running without Expo

Comment: You must be using `Flow` or something doing some type checking that you didn't mention in your question or the Snack. Cheers.

Comment: sometimes you got TypeError without using type checking

Comment: One problem with this approach is you can now get away with calling <InputButton> without passing onChange, since it has a default value, and you won't have any idea why it's not working.

Comment: I have to fix that in the future maybe some global dependency is making that error what kind of dependency can be the reason for that??

Answer (score 2):

`useState` does not immediately update the state -- it waits for the next run loop. So, you end up getting the previous state when you try to call `onChange` right after `setValue`.

You can use `useEffect` to get notified any time that `value` changes by doing this:

```
const updateValue = (option) => {
    if (isMultiple) {
      // onClick if option is not inclded in the array **add it** otherwise **remove it**
      !value.includes(option)
        ? setValue([...value, option])
        : setValue(value.filter((v) => v !== option));
    } else {
      setValue(option);
    }
    //onChange(value); //commented out here
  };

useEffect(() => { //added useEffect here
  onChange(value)
},[value,onChange]); //gets called whenever value changes
```

**Update**
Showing the code in context of the whole component:

```
const InputButton = ({ defaultValue = null, isMultiple = true, onChange }) => {
  const initValue = isMultiple ? defaultValue || [] : defaultValue;
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initValue);

  const updateValue = (option) => {
    if (isMultiple) {
      // onClick if option is not inclded in the array **add it** otherwise **remove it**
      !value.includes(option)
        ? setValue([...value, option])
        : setValue(value.filter((v) => v !== option));
    } else {
      setValue(option);
    }
    //onChange(value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(value)
  },[value,onChange]);

  console.log("if I log the value here it's good to go and updated, updated value is >", value)


  return (
    <View testID={'input-button'}>
      {options &&
        options.map((option, i) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={`${i}`}
            onPress={() => updateValue(option)}
            style={[
              isSelected(option, value) ? styles.selected : {},
              styles.button,
            ]}>
            <Text>{option}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: It gives me an error saying `onChange is not a function`

Comment: I'm not sure how that's possible -- you were using onChange before just fine. And I tested this using the Snack that you provided. Just take your original updateValue function and replace it with all the code I gave you.

Comment: Just updated with the whole component's code with my edits

Comment: but that the problem here I can't lift up that prop if i just put it inside of the updateValue it works fine but it fires before the state changes and if i put it outisde of the updateValue function it gives that error.

Comment: The goal is to have the two console logs read the same values, right? Meaning "value here" and "value outside the input button"?

Comment: Yeah exactly to get that value outside of the component